# How to move my cube on uneven terrain in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[this is my uneven terrain on which i want to move the cube.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0h11.png)

[this is my script which is attached to my cube in the scene. In here i am trying to move the
cube on the uneven terrain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGFvP.png)

Comment: It may make it easier for people to help if you paste the code as text in your question instead of as a picture. Also, could you provide more details on the behavior you're getting with your code and how it differs from your expected behavior?

Comment: I see you are using a `RigidBody`, why not just apply a force and let Unity work it out?  Job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to not use a cube collider for your cube but a "capsule". That one is rounded at the bottom. Then lock the rotation of the the rigidbody and apply forces in the direction you want to move it. Set the gravity factor accordingly. Then due to its rounded underside it will slide fairly well across terrain. You can influence how it slides by applying "physics materials" to both the terrain collider and the capsule.

That's at least the principle how most games work where characters can move freely across terrain and yet are not glued to the surface (allows jumping, falling off edges etc.).

Comment: Heyy man thank you its working fine now. :-). So that means the collider of the terrain gets automatically deformed(or adjusted) to the same shape when we actually deform(or change the shape) of the mesh of that terrain right ?

Comment: I also want to know that how can i achieve the same thing by using raycasting and setting positions every frame as i try to do it in the given image :-)

Comment: can you suggest something. ;-)

Comment: @TheNoobestGuy Think your mistake is to use hit.normal. This only represents a directional vector that's perpendicular to the surface (google "normal vector"). The actual position on the terrain is hit.point! Do not add the y component of that point to the current position but instead set it to exactly that value. Best if you don't do it all in one line of code.
Furthermore I'd suggest to never use "transform.position =" on objects controlled by rigid bodies. Instead get the rigidbody and use MovePosition(). This notifies the physics engine of that movement and allows for correct collissions.